# Por que o Ruby tem dois métodos send e __send__?

Tags: ruby

Objetos Ruby tem um método chamado `send` que podemos chamar métodos dinamicamente.

```
class MyClass
  private
  def true_method?
    true
  end
end
```

Exemplo:

```
mc = MyClass.new
mc.send(:true_method?)
mc.__send__(:true_method?)
```

> Por quê tem esses dois métodos?

Comment: Acho que tem uma pergunta semelhante no fórum internacional, Veja se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658269/ruby-send-vs-send

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tendo em vista que modificações dinâmicas, como sobrescritas de métodos é algo comum de se ver em Ruby, o [`Object#__send__` e `Object#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-send) é uma forma de proteger os objetos contra sobrescritas. O `__send__` serve como um alias interno, que você pode utilizar se seu objeto possui alguma redefinição de `send`. Por exemplo:

```
"hello world".send :upcase
=> "HELLO WORLD"

module EvilSend
  def send(foo)
    "Não foi dessa vez..."
  end
end

String.include EvilSend
"hello world".send :upcase
=> "Não foi dessa vez"

"hello world".__send__ :upcase
=> "HELLO WORLD"
```

Veja que não há nenhum warning do Ruby sobre a sobrescrita desse método. Por isso existe o `__send__`. O método que NÃO pode ser sobrescrito, em hipótese alguma, é o `__send__`. Se você tenta, [o Ruby lança um aviso](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/61c8247d55b0722b76b9d4d3adf78f70c01698bf/vm_method.c#L614).

> warning: redefining '`__send__`' may cause serious problems

Comment: Também descobri que se deve user o ____send____ quando vc implementa o send na sua classe. Por exemplo: Na sua classe UserNotification vc tem um método send, pra vc user o send do Object vc usa o ____send____

Comment: Acredito que esse comportamento está atrelado a questão de classes abertas, faz sentido?